# Can't able to create temp table using Dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create a temp table in MS sql server. It's shows like table is created and value(s) are inserted. While using Select query, it throws an error.

My sample code is

```
EXEC (
        'create table #temp2 (id int)
         insert #temp2 values(1)'
        )

SELECT *
FROM #temp2
```

The output is

> (1 row affected) 
>   Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 8
>   Invalid object name '#temp2'.

Comment: A temporary table only exists, and can only be referenced in the sessions it's created in; you can't use `EXEC` to create a new session and then reference the table. Why are you using `EXEC` here anyway? There's nothing Dynamic about your query.

Comment: A temporary table created in an `EXEC` is dropped when the `EXEC` completes. Although `EXEC` does not, in fact, create a new session, it does create a new, separate scope for temp tables.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. This is my sample code. In my actual code I having different number of columns in different column types according to user. So i need to create a temp table dynamically.

Comment: Then your only recourse is to move all statements, including those that access the table, into the `EXEC`. Generally this kind of code gets extremely unwieldy and you should strongly consider either changing your approach altogether to remove the reliance on dynamic objects (for example, you could use key-value tables), or doing this from client code.

Comment: Jeroem Mostert, Is there any solution to create an temp table and use it in same session?

Comment: You might want to actually show us something that is representative of your code, as that'll greatly help us help you.

Comment: @JereonMostert you're right; scope is a better definition here.

Comment: Technically, creating a global temp table (`##temp2`) will prevent it from getting dropped. Practically, you need to be careful with this because global temp tables, as the name implies, are visible to all sessions, so you almost certainly want to generate a unique name dynamically as well, to prevent clashes on parallel executions. Like I said -- unwieldy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the temp table in the same procedure so it's still in scope, then use dynamic SQL to modify it.

```
create table #temp2 (id int) 

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000) ='ALTER TABLE #temp2 ADD test1 int NOT NULL, test2 int NOT NULL'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

insert #temp2 values(1,2,3)

SELECT * FROM #temp2

DROP TABLE #temp2
```